# Python send emails using ipaddress

Tags: python, email, smtp

I am trying to send emails by Python, using SMTP relay, I dont have access to the real SMTP from my Outlook account, My ip address is added to smtp relay server. I tried to run my code just using my ipaddress but failed.

Error ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

```
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import smtplib
 
# create message object instance
msg = MIMEMultipart()
 
 
message = "Thank you"
 
# setup the parameters of the message
password = "myPassword"
msg['From'] = "myemail@gmail.com"
msg['To'] = "myemail@gmail.com"
msg['Subject'] = "Subscription"
 
# add in the message body
msg.attach(MIMEText(message, 'plain'))
 
#create server
server = smtplib.SMTP('Here I put my Ip address')  
 
server.starttls()
 
# Login Credentials for sending the mail
server.login(msg['From'], password)
 
 
# send the message via the server.
server.sendmail(msg['From'], msg['To'], msg.as_string())
 
server.quit()
 
print ("successfully sent email to %s:" % (msg['To']))
```

Regards

Comment: "smtplib.SMTP('Here I put my Ip address')" - are you not supposed to use the IP address of the relay server here?

Comment: Yes, I used the IP address but didn't work.

Comment: Then I suggest you consult with your network administrators.

Comment: "I used the IP address " - yes but which IP address? Yours or that of the relay server? If yours, why?

Comment: The admin added my ip address to smtp relay server now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ip address and port of the relay should go here:
`server = smtplib.SMTP('RELAY_IP_HERE', RELAY_SMTP_PORT_HERE)`

Also, it could be blocked by the firewall on the relay machine. If you have admin access to the server, you could try checking the SMTP service. You could try using telnet to check if the port is open. Here's a link that describes how to perform the checks using telnet from a windows machine:
https://support.hostway.com/hc/en-us/articles/360002236820-How-to-Test-SMTP-Services-Manually-in-Windows-Server

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, how I can get the relay smtp port?

Comment: "how I can get the relay SMTP port" - you get that information from your network administrators.

Comment: I suggest you read again the first paragraph of the answer above.